# How to find docker image for a container?

Tags: python, docker, containers

I am trying to find the corresponding docker image for a container.

```
docker inspect <container-id>
```

This gives a whole lot of information. It also gives the docker image if I do :
    docker inspect  ['Config']['Image']

But this is not the reliable source as some times it just gives some SHA, something like `sha256:00954e990edd7c78dff64c8031c58c07cb36b4591dca3923b5a1a1c31199e54c`

Is there a reliable way to find the docker image for a container?

Especially through Python code.

I have docker client but that doesn't support any query that can give me Image name.

Comment: Are you using Docker SDK from python?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`docker inspect <container-id>` gives you the `Image` property, as you've noticed:

```
"Image": "sha256:8d6721e9290e96cc34faeee7a525311a400598e7fee170190c73ce103dd621ce"
```

You can use that hash value to subsequently inspect the image itself: `docker inspect <image-id>`. In the example above "8d6721e9290e96cc34faeee7a525311a400598e7fee170190c73ce103dd621ce" is the image ID.

Comment: aaha ... thanks. That gives me docker image under RepoTags, why it is an array ?

Comment: You can apply multiple tags to the same image, they'll be listed there.

Comment: so which one would give me the image repotag or repodigests?
If there are multiple repotags how would I know which is the base image?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking; by base image do you mean the one from which your 8d6721e9 image was built?

Answer (score 0):

ok I jsut checked docker image inspect also works with the sha.. hash so I asume the sdk ( which probably just passes it along to cmd ) should also be able to handle it like in this example

```
>>> client.containers.list()
[<Container '45e6d2de7c54'>, <Container 'db18e4f20eaa'>, ...]

>>> container = client.containers.get('45e6d2de7c54')

>>> container.attrs['Config']['Image']
"bfirsh/reticulate-splines"

>>> container.logs()
"Reticulating spline 1...\n"

>>> container.stop()
```